# Tab visibility in Lightning experience

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

Now we are switching to lightning,so we are checking whether the custom pages developed using visualforce are accessible in lightning.So here is one issue that is we are facing...
I have a link in a visualforce page on click of which the another visualforce page opens in new window..The problem in lightning is that the tabs are not displaying for that..
Below are the screeshot of the page in classic and lightning view

In classic
[image]

In lightning
[image]

Please let me know how we can make tabs available in lightning

```
 <apex:commandLink status="actStatusId" value="{!$Label.SG_China_SG_China_Edit_Cost_Center}" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="pbblock">
                            <apex:param name="interactionsortField" value="Name" assignTo="{!interactionsortField}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
 </apex:facet>
<apex:outputLink value="/apex/SGChinaFCUpdateCostCenter?selectedRecordId={!eachRecord.id}&setselectedobject=SAEvent" target="_blank">{!$Label.SG_China_SG_China_Edit_Cost_Center} </apex:outputLink>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide more details here?

Comment: yeah tushaar,above in the screenshot i have displayed the view in classic as well as lightining...In classic you can see that the tabs home,SA Events are visible ...but in lightning those tabs are not visible....

Comment: Share the URL you are using to open the page.

Comment: Hi Tushar,Updated the question with the URL